# Change Desktop's font family

Tags: fonts, gtk, css, tweak, theme-development

I can change filename's colors with that css file. (gtk.css)

But I can't set the font or bold property, it is still default font and bold.

---

How can I change font familiy or font weight? Thanks! - ( Eg. Image of my desktop: )

[image: My Desktop]

Comment: No answers... ?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? Are you using any other desktop environment. Is that Adobe photoshop icon in WINE?

Comment: 16.04, no it's default.

Comment: Yes, it is in WINE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desktop font's key location in dconf database has been changed. To change desktop font in Ubuntu 16.04 or later use this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Noto Sans 11'
```

Here I used `Noto Sans` as the font and `11` as size. Use any other font and size you use. If you want to use **bold** variant, add `bold` after the font name in the command.

Same can be done using `dconf-editor` by navigating to the respective directories.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Install `dconf editor` :-> `sudo apt install dconf-editor`:

   - go to `org --> gnome --> nautilus --> desktop` and change what you need:
   - [image]

Comment: Both are changing general font of system, but If you look the desktop font, I just want to make it bolder, I don't want any font changes on the system.